# Error on value column in group by value counts

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have code below as:

```
df[('name')]['cash_amount'].valuecounts(normalize=True).sum()
```

I want to use valuecounts normalize true,  because I want to calculate the % of each names cash over the total amount of cash in the column.

Where I am trying to calculate the total number each name has in the cash_amount column,
but I get error that says - **KeyError: 'cash_amount'**

df looks like

input:

```
name | cash_amount
bob      $400
chris    $500
amy      $100
amy      $100
bob      $100
bob      $100
```

output:

```
name |  % 
bob    .46
chris  .38
amy    .15
```

I looked for any white spaces in the column name and tried `df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()` and still get same error

Comment: can you return the result of `df.columns` verbatim?

Comment: Can you do `df.columns`? I bet you have whitespace, e.g. `' cash_amount'` or  `'cash_amount ' `. I think you can do`df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()` if you want to clean up whitespaces prior to running your code.

Comment: although looking at the syntax, why do you have `[('name')]`?  If `df` is your dataframe and  `cash_amount` is a column name, that may cause errors.  I don't know what `[('name')]` would refer to.

Comment: they are both columns

Comment: well try `df['cash_amount'].value_counts(normalize=True)`

Comment: I want it sorted by names of the people too

Comment: that's a separate issue.  you can use `df.sort_values("name")` for that

Comment: no I have the expected output above, your solution of the df['cash_amount'].value_counts(normalize=True) does not group by names

Comment: @DavidErickson I looked for white spaces and no white spaces, also if I do it runs so not problem with column name I think

Comment: @Chris90 can you just look at my answer? If it's wrong I will delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First remove the `$` from your string and convert to `float` or `int`. `$` is a regex character, so you need to escape it with `\`. Then `.groupby` and get the percentage of total by getting the sum for each group and dividing it by the toal sum:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': {0: 'bob', 1: 'chris', 2: 'amy', 3: 'amy', 4: 'bob', 5: 'bob'},
 'cash_amount': {0: '$400', 1: '$500', 2: '$100', 3: '$100', 4: '$100', 5: '$100'}})
df['cash_amount'] = df['cash_amount'].str.replace('\$', '').astype(float)
df = ((df.groupby('name')['cash_amount'].sum() / df['cash_amount'].sum())
      .rename('%').reset_index())
df
Out[1]: 
    name         %
0    amy  0.153846
1    bob  0.461538
2  chris  0.384615
```

Comment: Thanks! , one question, when I try to run code, I get error of below

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str' @David Erickson

Comment: is it because in the csv where this df is coming from the column type is currency and has $400, $30 instead of just numbers in your example? @David Erickson

Comment: @Chris90 run the new code. Your column is made up of strings, because there are `$` in them. You need to get rid of the `$`.

Answer (score 1):

Please use `df.replace`, `groupby()` and apply lambda grouped sum divided by total sum

```
 df['cash_amount']=df.replace(regex=r'\$', value='')['cash_amount'].astype(int)
(df.groupby('name').cash_amount.apply(lambda x: x.sum())/df.cash_amount.sum()).rename('%').reset_index()


 name         %
0    amy  0.153846
1    bob  0.461538
2  chris  0.384615
```